# Можно ли через API Вконтакте отправлять сообщения на email?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, email

В ВК, как известно, любой юзер может отправить сообщение на email. Можно ли реализовать это через API?(аналог https://vk.com/write?email=mail@mail.ru)

Comment: А в методы api смотрели?

Comment: Да, я там просмотрел почти все, но может что-то ушло от моего взора или есть какой то потайной способ

Comment: Похоже что нет -- только через сайт. Попробуйте спросить поддержку вк

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо